# Removing the query string and redirecting (rewrite rule and rewrite cond)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently trying to set up a rewrite rule to set up an internal redirect for a more SEO-friendly url-structure.

I want to show:

```
/find-teacher/primary-school.php
```

instead of the sad looking:

```
/find-teacher/subject-class-choose.php?school=primary-school
```

After I read some posts and tutorials about the rewrite rule and rewrite cond, I came up with this:

In my choose-school.php I have as a link with the nice looking url:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/find-teacher/primary-school.php">
Primary School</a>
```

In my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^find-teacher/primary-school.php$
RewriteRule ^find-teacher/([a-z-]+)-([0-9]+).php$ /find-teacher/subject-class-choose.php?school=$1 [NC]
```

Now if I got that right, the `RewriteCond` part checks if the following url is requested. If that is the case, then the part of `([a-z-]+)-([0-9]+)` is replaced by the `$1` of the substitution part (`/find-teacher/subject-class-choose.php?school=$1`)

Problem is that I am redirected to my error page if I click on `/find-teacher/primary-school.php`

Comment: Is query string `school_id=1` denotes primary school data?

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar Sorry, I changed it to `school_id=primary-school`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need both a RewriteCond and a RewriteRule here, because they are (or should be) both checking the same thing.

However, currently, there is no URL which will match both patterns. Let's break down the problem.

To check specifically for the URL `/find-teacher/primary-school.php`, you could just write:

```
RewriteRule ^find-teacher/primary-school.php$ /find-teacher/subject-class-choose.php?school=primary-school [NC]
```

The next step is to "capture" the "primary-school" with `(` and `)`, and place it dynamically onto the target with `$1`:

```
RewriteRule ^find-teacher/(primary-school).php$ /find-teacher/subject-class-choose.php?school=$1 [NC]
```

Finally, we can make the pattern match any letters or hyphens instead of an exact string, using the regex `[a-z-]+`:

```
RewriteRule ^find-teacher/([a-z-]+).php$ /find-teacher/subject-class-choose.php?school=$1 [NC]
```

In the rule in your question, you've added an extra part to the regex: `-([0-9]+)`. This matches `-` and then a number. To capture that number, you'd put `$2` somewhere in your target:

```
RewriteRule ^find-teacher/([a-z-]+)-([0-9]+).php$ /find-teacher/subject-class-choose.php?school=$1&id=$2 [NC]
```

This would match something like `/find-teacher/primary-school-123.php`, and turn it into `/find-teacher/subject-class-choose.php?school=primary-school&id=123`.

Two final notes:

- *depending how your Apache configuration is set up*, you *may or may not* need to include the leading `/` in your patterns, i.e. start them with `^/`
- I find a nice way to debug rewrite rules is to make them redirect your browser, by adding `R=temp` to the flags (e.g. `[NC,R=temp]`); that way, you don't have to rely on your PHP code to tell you what URL was requested

Comment: Thanks a lot! My page `/find-teacher/primary-school.php` now redirects to `/find-teacher/subject-class-choose.php?school=primary-school`. Problem though is, I thought this is an "internal" redirect invisible for the visitor and SEO-friendly - if I redirect from the link to the sad looking url it is still displayed as the target url in the url adress bar. I've been checking more tutorials, but all of them state this would be "invisible" and "internal" now though it is not on my side :(. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Franky2207 With the `[R]` flag, the browser is told to go to the new URL; without it, Apache just "pretends" you are on the new URL, without telling the browser. You might also want to add the `[L]` (for "Last") flag, to stop other rules further down the config from causing additional redirects. Note that if you use `[R]` without `=temp`, it will issue a "permanent" redirect, and your browser will probably cache that redirect, more or less forever; test with a slightly different URL to make sure that's not the issue.

Comment: Thanks again. So does it mean, I have to use the `[R]` flag, because otherwise the redirect does not work properly? I think I don't really get the difference between telling and pretending to the browser. If I leave out the `[R]` flag, it shows up `/primary-school.php` as it should. It also transfers the value via the `$_GET` from `school_id`. Is it still not recommendable to leave out the `[R]` flag? I also tried it with a different URL and using the `[L]` flag, but it still leads to a "sad url" in the adress bar if I include `[R=temp]`.

Comment: In your case, leaving out the `[R]` flag is correct. It's not about recommended or not, it's about different use cases. If you want to say "you've typed an old or wrong URL, go here instead", you would want to tell the browser, so would use `[R]`; in your case, you want to say "that's a nice URL, I know what you mean", so would *not* use `[R]`. I may have confused you with my note that sometimes using `[R=temp]` is useful *for testing*, because you can see the result of it more easily when it shows up in your address bar; once you're done testing, you'd take the flag away.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I got it now :) really kind to help me out!